# error filling in testfield using mysql and php javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

slightly varied question but I have a script that runs and gets data from a mysql db. The end result shows them as buttons, when i click the buttons it gives me an alert with the correct id number correspsonding to whats selected, but when i try to put that into a textfield is isnt the same, its basically the last in the mysql? WHy would the alert show the correct and the updated textfield so totally different information??

The working php that alerts the correct info is :

```
    <?php

 include('config.php');

 $action = $_REQUEST['action'];

 if($action=="showAll"){

  $stmt=$dbcon->prepare('SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_name');
  $stmt->execute();

 }else{

  $stmt=$dbcon->prepare('SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products WHERE cat_id=:cid ORDER BY product_name');
  $stmt->execute(array(':cid'=>$action));
 }

 ?>
 <div class="row">
 <?php
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   extract($row);

   ?>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
   <div style="border-radius:3px; border:#cdcdcd solid 1px; padding:22px;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="alert('<? echo $product_id; ?>')"><?php echo $product_name; ?></button></div><br />
   </div>
   <?php  
  }

 }else{

  ?>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
   <div style="border-radius:3px; border:#cdcdcd solid 1px; padding:22px;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="alert('<? echo $product_id; ?>')"><?php echo $product_name; ?></button></div><br />
  </div>
        <?php  
 }


 ?>
 </div>

 <div>
 text : <input id="textField1" type="text" value="0" align="right" size="13"/><br>
 </div>

 <script>
function display()
    {
        document.getElementById("textField1").value = "<? echo $product_name; ?>";
    }
</script>
```

But if change the button to use the 'display script' it just shows last in database?